# Google places api time spent

Tags: google-places-api, google-places

I want to create a layout plan for tourist with help of google places apis. I have to define their itinerary for eg. visit from A to b place(stay for 1h at A place) travel for 10 min and go to b place. I can find all of relevant data in google api, but anyone can help me, how would I find (time spent by user  at particular place). Google places api is no help in this, any other api, any help?

Comment: There is no such feature in the API, please consider [filing a feature request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request)

Comment: Hi, Ashok. How do you resolved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Places API and the other Maps APIs do not offer that information, in fact that kind of tracking is forbidden under [Google Maps API - 9.3 End User Terms and Privacy Policy](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_9_3).

> 2. If your Maps API Implementation provides Google with geolocation data, that geolocation data must not enable Google to identify an individual user. For example, if your Maps API Implementation sends Google Your Content, and Your Content includes geolocation data, Your Content must not also include unique device identifiers associated with individual users.

Comment: I have seen websites like inspirock.com implements, user stay at particular places for a certain time. How did they implement it?